# Create your own dependency for Android

Tags: android, dependencies

Hi guys i was wondering how you can make your own dependyncy in android so that you can use it on every project that you make? something like this compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'`. Any ideas where to start with?

Comment: it has something to do with this I think: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html but I've never done it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your jar to maven central: http://kirang89.github.io/blog/2013/01/20/uploading-your-jar-to-maven-central/

Or create module and add it to each of your projects: `compile project(':MyModule')`